# Incidence of mail clients not supporting html

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

Anybody know the current percentage of users with mail clients not supporting html?  Is it safe to just send only html emails?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about mail client percentages, although even text-mode clients support HTML these days. There is however a very good reason to NOT send HTML-only mail. From one of my SpamAssassin reports:

1.9 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts

Unless you *want* your mail to be dropped in the trashcan, do not send HTML-only messages.

Comment: Well this is a great point, hadn't considered anti-spam issues.

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend a lot on your target demographic, but more often than not the number of non-HTML email recipients these days is fairly small.  And those who explicitly turn off HTML support in their email client usually know what they're doing and have a good reason (and expect what they get).

If you're talking about sending emails to a list of users for, say, a website then one common suggestion is to have a user setting in the UI where they can specify HTML or text-only emails (or even opt out, but that's your call).  It means making the same emails/templates twice, which may be more effort than it's worth for your needs, but it's something.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly *not* safe to send HTML-only e-mails.  Regardless of e-mail client support for HTML, there are user preferences that aren't possible to measure.  Another thing to keep in mind is the huge number of mobile devices that prefer to read the text version, as their HTML rendering is sub-par at best.

You should be sending out both versions of your e-mail.  There is no reason not to.

You might also find this useful, for figuring out what is supported in e-mail clients:  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/